Как настроить порты в Docker Swarm
У меня есть docker-compose файл, который я использую для запуска Docker Swarm
version: '3.8'
services:
frontend:
image: image:tag
deploy:
    replicas: 3
ports:
  - 127.0.0.1:8080:8080

Но при запуске docker stack deploy он выдает ошибку адреса 127.0.0.1 и запускается на 0.0.0.0
Но меня такой вариант не устраивает, потому что в таком случае подключится к контейнеру можно извне минуя nginx
Настраивать iptables пытался, но Docker своими настройками в нём всё равно пропускает подключения
Подскажите, какой вариант есть сделать подключение к контейнеру исключительно локальным ?
И раз docker swarm заставляет делать такие костыли, проще ли будет с K8s ?
p.s. я не девопс, и в делах девопсерских слабо соображаю, поэтому скорее всего чего-то не понимаю.

а что мне даст обратный прокси nginx?

и я же правильно понимаю, что если Iptables не помог, то как поможет firewalld?

а можете скинуть пример кода, что нужно добавить в nginx конфиг ? потому что те варианты что я находил не работали

Я пришёл сюда явно не потому, что не знаю про существование гугла. Лучше уж ничего не отвечать, чем на форуме посвященному вопросам отвечать про гугл

Решение оказалось простым. Установка пакета ufw-docker настраивает iptables поверх настроек докера, и блокирует все подключения к докеру из вне по умолчанию, даже если контейнер запущен в 0.0.0.0 (как в случае в docker swarm).
